# While parsing a xml file receiving " xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
def get_attr_number(node):
    root=ET.fromstring(node)
    length=0
    for i in root:
        l=len(i.attrib)
        length+=l
    print (length)

if __name__=="__main__":
    n=int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        node=input()
        print (node)
        get_attr_number(node)
```

I am not able to pass the xml string to the function here.Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future reference, after pasting code into your question, select it and type Ctrl-K to format it properly.

Comment: Can you add a simple example of input (`n`, `node`) that produces the issue?

Comment: Here n is the no. of lines of a xml string and node is a xml string.
eg:n=6
node=<feed xml:lang='en'>
    <title>Deparment</title>
    <subtitle lang='en'>Programming challenges</subtitle>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://department.com/'/>
    <updated>2013-12-25T12:00:00</updated>
</feed>

Comment: I don't get an error with those inputs.

Comment: when i m passing n=6 and 
node=<feed xml:lang='en'> <title>Deparment</title> <subtitle lang='en'>Programming challenges</subtitle> <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='department.com/'/>; <updated>2013-12-25T12:00:00</updated> </feed> 
then i m getting *xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 20* error